# Error while trying angular ng route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im Trying to use angular routes (beginner).

Error : `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

My Code : javascript

```
var indexapp = angular.module('indexApp',[]);

    indexapp.config(function($roteProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/hello' , {
        templateUrl:'app/views/explore.html'
      })
    });
```

HTML:
just I added `<div ng-view></divh>`

The Routs is not working + the error on top

Answer (score 1):

as [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) says you have to add angular-route script `<script src="angular-route.js">` to your HTML. Then inject `ngRoute` to your app.

```
var indexapp = angular.module('indexApp',['ngRoute']);
indexapp.config(['$routeProvider'], function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/hello' , {
        templateUrl:'app/views/explore.html'
      })
    });
```

And you have an error in `<div ng-view></div>`

Comment: Spelling mistake also when you injecting. $roteProvider should be $routeProvider

Answer (score 0):

Add ngRoute dependency while registering the module,

```
  var indexapp = angular.module('indexApp',['ngRoute']);
```